# How to represent very long integers with at-most-8-digit(base-10) short integers with * and +

Tags: string-manipulation, factorization, prime-numbers

I need an algorithm in Mathematica, which can represent any very long integer, prime or not, into the the product operation "*" and sum "+" forms by short integers (not more than 8 decimal digits).

Additional rules on the final expression of the very long integer are:

(1). the lengths (base-10 decimal digits) of all short prime integers employed should
    be as close to 6 as possible, the closer the better;

if there are *n* different short integers used, we use the sum of squared differences between their lengths and 6 as the criterion: the smaller the better (first priority);

(2). the less "+" operators used the better (second priority); the less "*" the better(the third priority).

The final expression of the integer should be usable immediately in C/C++.

Example numbers for testing:

```
29427736469514379027531261659072347
58899562724319710108573382000184640
1732944474195510410991057714955859184
```

Is there any Mathematica implementation of such algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: `short integers (not more than 6 decimal digits).`  Can you clarify this with an example? How can an integer have decimal digits? something with decimal point is not an integer, right? or are you using different notations?

Comment: @Nasser sometimes "decimal digits" is used to make it clear base-10 is used to count digits

Comment: @Nasser ssch, thanks. I mean base-10 integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after but maybe if its not it will help you clarify the question:

```
long = RandomInteger[10^30];
base = 2^32;
repr = IntegerDigits[long, base];
Total@MapIndexed[ #1 base^(First@#2 - 1) &, Reverse@ repr] == long 
StringJoin[
  MapIndexed[
      If[First@#2 > 1, "+", ""] <> ToString[#1 ] <> 
        Table[ "*" <> ToString[ base], {First@#2 - 1}] &, Reverse@ repr]]

(*
613921084644306481276815940460
True
"3623623532+1291570358*4294967296+3215957613*4294967296*4294967296+7*4294967296*4294967296*4294967296"
*)
```

I see you asked for 6 digits max , just make the base smaller..

Edit: alternate approach that tries to use mostly large numbers..

```
long = RandomInteger[10^20]
base = 999999;
reduce[ long_ /; long > base] :=
  Module[{n = Ceiling[Log[long]/Log[base]], p1},
          {#, n, reduce[long - #^n]} &@Floor[long^(1/n)]]
reduce[ long_] := {long, 1};
repr = Partition[Flatten@reduce[long], 2];
Total[#[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@ repr] == long
StringJoin@
  Flatten[Riffle[
    Riffle[Table[ ToString[#[[1]]], {#[[2]]}], "*"] & /@ repr , "+"]] 

 (*
   49745600692119322339
   True
   "83982*83982*83982*83982+104024*104024*104024+149275*149275+17914"
 *)
```

first approach for this number and base gives:

```
   "760108+183469*999999+745749*999999*999999+49*999999*999999*999999"
```